# why does ngOnInit() execute multiple times for setInterval()?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngoninit

I am very beginner in Angular.

```
export class CountComponent implements OnInit {

  public no:number;

  constructor() { 
     this.no=0;
  }

  public myfun():void{
     this.no++;
     alert(this.no);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.myfun();
  }
}
```

when I run the above code, alert() is popup only once. Which means ngOnInit() only executes once.
But

```
export class CountComponent implements OnInit {
  public no:number;

  constructor() { 
    this.no=0;
  }

  public myfun():void{
      setInterval(()=>{
        this.no++;
        alert(this.no);
      },1000);
  }
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myfun();
  }
}
```

when I run above code, alert() popups repeatedly. Which means ngOnInit() executes multiple times continuously (or myfun() executes multiple times).

so my problem is why does ngOnInit() execute multiple times instead of once, when I add setInterval() in myfun() ?

please give me full explanation & forgive me if this question is already asked.

Comment: maybe you wanted to use `setTimeout` istead of `setInterval` ? ngOnInit is called 1 time. problem is in the logic

Comment: yeah maybe `setTimeout` makes `ngOnInit` execute once. But please explain me why `setInterval` makes `ngOnInit` execute multiple times?. I am searching for the reason

Comment: It doesn’t execute ngOninit multiple times.. it executes the callback in setInterval multiple times.. maybe you should read up on what setInterval is..?

Answer (score 0):

1000 = 1 seg,  try to increase the value

Comment: But could you please explain why `setInterval` makes `ngOnInit` execute multiple times?. I am searching for the reason

Comment: is not making the ngOnInit multiple times, the interval is the cycle that repeats in the period of time provided